# Add delays between UIView Animations

Tags: objective-c, animation, delay

I have some operations and animations inside the touchesBegan method of UIView which I subclassed and append as class in my View.
I need some delay between the animations.

Code:

```
- (void) touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    // Add delay to imitate the hold for touch 1 second and if true continue
    // else cancel everything

    [self animateViewSize]; // Here animates the view frame

    // Add delay until sizing animation ends.....

    [self animateViewFlip]; // Here animates the view flip y axis

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"A Notification" object:self];
    // Notify the superview Controller that touch happened and do some operations with  animations too...

    // Some variables appending values for the UIView location when it touched
}

- (void) animateCardSize
{
    // Animate using UIView animation
}
- (void) animateFlipView
{
     // Animate flip using CABasicAnimation
}
```

This is the basic idea.....

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could also use in your method

```
[self performSelector:@selector(animateCardSize) withObject:nil afterDelay:(2.0f)];
//2.0 and animateCardSize as examples
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do so with Block-based UiView animations:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.4 animations:^{
    //Your first anim here
} completion:^(BOOL finished){
    //Your second anim here
}];
```

Comment: Thanx for comment I have a block-based animation for sizing so I added the second flip animation in the completion code, solved a problem. What about the touch delay I need before animation begins and before notify?